# How to bind an `ObservableCollection` to Grid with Rows/Columns specified in the objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have something like this inside a grid:

```
    <Ellipse Grid.Row="{Binding Path=Game.Tiles[2].Row}"
             Grid.Column="{Binding Path=Game.Tiles[2].Column}"
             Fill="{Binding Game.Tiles[2].FillColor}"
             Stroke ="{StaticResource TileStroke}"></Ellipse>
```

How do I enumerate over all 24 objects without typing this 24 times?

Comment: Is this in a WPF context? Also could you explain your problem a bit better? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, it is in a `UserControl` and inside a `Grid`.

Comment: Have you tried doing it from code behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have a list/collection of objects displayed, you need to employ an "ItemsControl" of sorts. In this case, the following fragment might be of help:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Game.Tiles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Position}">
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding FillColor}"
                     Stroke="{StaticResource TileStroke}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Remember to put in the right DataType for the DataTemplate and enough rows/columns into the Grid to hold your data.

Also it is not quite as easy to include an unknown number of rows/columns. If that is of interest, I could be getting back to you with a solution, but the original post read like the idea of a game board - like checkers - so I assume the number of columns/rows is constant.

Comment: This solution does not include Fill and Stroke properties. Moreover, number of rows could be unknown at compile time. Edit: Ok, he especially wants 24 rows but it would be nice if you provided a solution that involves unknown number of rows.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it seems like a lot of magic to me :P